# Garbage collector

Tags: javascript

Как насильно вызвать `Garbage Collector`?есть ли такая функция? например, в `java` есть метод `finalize()`,который позволяет вызвать `Garbage Collector`,есть ли такая возможность в `JS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, управление памятью в JavaScript выполняется автоматически и незаметно.

Прочитать более детально можно к примеру [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection)

Answer (score 3):

Есть вроде как в Опере и как минимум старом эксплорере - но даже там ее вызывать не рекомендуется. Все происходит автоматически.

Comment: delete работает только для свойств объекта, однако... Приведенный код в обычном режиме просто ничего не сделает, в "use strict" выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Я тоже так думал, но при ответе на этот вопрос пришла в голову идея проверить, способен ли на такое `delete`. И, похоже, то ли посмотрел не туда, то ли словил сонный паралич... Ибо тогда дописал ответ на основе своей проверки, а сейчас, разумеется, вижу, что ошибся. Большое спасибо, отредактирую ответ!